# Using static properties to initialise object properties

Tags: php, properties, static, initialization, member

I have a Class that owns various properties which can be modified.
All of the properties have default values defined.

```
class Model {
    protected $name = 'defaultName';
}
```

Now I would like to make it possible to change the default values globally.

I tried the following:

```
class Model {
    protected static $defaultName = 'defaultName';
    protected $name = self::$defaultName;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"'

So I guess it's caused by the fact that you can't use expressions for initialisations or something similar?
Or is this possible without setting the property value inside the constructor?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find the correct answer because everything else seems to focus on initialisation of static properties while my problem is about initialising the object member.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's what a constructor is for, why are you trying to avoid using it?

Comment: @Rikesh: as I mentioned your example only refers to initialising the static property, which is working fine for me… I have a problem on initialising the object property

Comment: @Wrikken: Well I would like use declarations instead of active coding

Comment: @steeeffeen: well, you're currently out of luck [but it is up for consideration and voted on as a rfc for php](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs). As there were more 'yes' voted you could check whether the current development branche of PHP has the patch merged. _[edit: apparenty it should be in 5.6 since 2013-11-03]_

Comment: @Wrikken: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately the change only covers constants.

Comment: ah yes, I mixed up my class connstants & class static variables, apologies. So: then there's absolutely no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I guess it's caused by the fact that you can't use expressions for initialisations or something similar?

Yes. From 5.6 onwards you could formulate it more correctly as "you can't use *dynamic* expressions for initialisations".

> Or is this possible without setting the property value inside the constructor?

No, unless you use class constants instead of static fields; unfortunately, those have the side effect that they're accessible from outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can not do the way you are trying, you can use __construct() to do so.

Here is the example

```
class Model
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'defaultName';
    protected $name = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = self::$defaultName;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name ;
    }
}

$m = new Model();
echo $m->getName();
// outputs defaultName
```

Comment: Thanks but my question was "Or is this possible without setting the property value inside the constructor?"
So you can assume that i'm aware of constructors ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Model {
    protected static $defaultName;
    protected $name;

    function __construct(){
        self::$defaultName = 'defaultName';
        $this->name = self::defaultName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my question was "Or is this possible without setting the property value inside the constructor?"
So you can assume that I'm aware of the solution using a constructor ;)

Comment: You can't access protected properties outside the class, so the sole way to set it is doing it in class method. Best place for it is __construct function, why do you avoid it?

Comment: Well the protected visibility isn't a problem because my code example doesn't have an "outside" context
I would simply like to use declarations instead of active coding so you can easily see which values the properties have instead of having to search for coding that shows which values they will have

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Model {
    const CONSTANT = 'my value';

    protected static $defaultName = self::CONSTANT;
    protected $name = self::CONSTANT;
}
```